# Getting SID of users

Tags: winapi, sid

I’m writing an application on Windows XP which gives the SID of  user.

With the valid token handle, when I call `GetTokenInfomation` API with `TokenUser` as a second parameter then every time & for all user account I get Valid SID in `PTOKEN_USER` structure variable.

Valid Sid =>  Sid is `S-1-5-21-1121170692-2157880286-4158546613-1000`

Here RID is  => 1000

But when I use `NetQueryDisplayInformation` API with `NET_DISPLAY_USER` as a information level (second parameter) then I get `NET_DISPLAY_USER` structure as a out Parameter.

`User123` is my one account which has the administrative rights.

With the help of `NET_DISPLAY_USER` structure when I call to `LookupAccountName` API with variable of `NET_DISPLAY_USER.usri1_name` as a name of the user account then for a `User123` account I get SID without RID.

e.g.
Like this =>  Sid is `S-1-5-21-1121170692-2157880286-4158546613`

For other account with same procedure gives me the correct SID i.e. SID with RID

e.g. 
Valid Sid =>  Sid is `S-1-5-21-1121170692-2157880286-4158546613-1000`

Please provide me any pointers for returning SID without RID in second case.

Comment: Are you sure you want the SID without RID? Or do you mean a SID with the RID, even for User123? And if you really do mean without RID, what are you going to do with that SID?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot have a (valid) user SID without that final RID so something must be wrong with the lookup. Are you sure your call to LookupAccountName succeeds? What is the value of your SID_NAME_USE after a successful call to LookupAccountName?

[A comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#CommunityContentHeader) on MSDN indicates that LookupAccountName will return the wrong value if the user name and machine name are the same but I assume your machine is not called "User123".

> Please provide me any pointers for returning SID without RID in second
>   case.

Are you sure you really want this? If you do you can just convert to string, chop off the last "-xxx" part and convert back but I don't think I would pass that SID to any other function since it might not be valid. (And only do it when the SID_NAME_USE you got is SidTypeUser)

Comment: Hey Anders my machine name and username is not same. GetTokenInfomation  API gives me full SID of the user say user123 but when I use NetQueryDisplayInformation API then for same user user123 it's not giving me SID with RID. I need full SID with the  help of NetQueryDisplayInformation  API.                                                For other accounts except user123 the NetQueryDisplayInformation API gives me valid SID with RID.

Comment: Does LookupAccountName succeed and what is the returned SID_NAME_USE?